# Getting SELECT statement has a cartesian product warning while retrieving results using joinedload in ORM query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

Following are the 2 tables in the database I have created.

```
class BusinessRole:
    __tablename__ = 'businessrole'

    id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    approval_status = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default=BRApprovalStatus.VOID.value)
    approval = db.relationship('Approval', backref='approval')
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


class Approval:
    __tablename__ = 'approval'
    
    id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
    requester = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    approver = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
```

So the database has multiple records of the same value for example:

```
 1. Business_Role_1, updated_on: 2023-05-02, version: 2
 2. Business_Role_1, updated_on: 2023-05-01, version: 1
 3. Business_Role_2, updated_on: 2023-04-30, version: 3
 4. Business_Role_2, updated_on: 2023-04-29, version: 2
 5. Business_Role_2, updated_on: 2023-04-28, version: 1
```

So I am only retrieving those values that are updated lately and have the highest version value. here is the query below I have written in order to do so.

```
sub_query = db.session.query(
        BusinessRole.name,
        func.max(BusinessRole.version).label('max_version'),
        func.max(BusinessRole.updated_on).label('latest_updated_on')
    ).filter(
        or_(and_(BusinessRole.status == BRStatus.APPROVED.value,
                 BusinessRole.approval_status == BRApprovalStatus.COMPLETED.value),
            and_(BusinessRole.status.in_([BRStatus.DRAFT.value, BRStatus.NEW.value, BRStatus.DENIED.value])))
    ).group_by(BusinessRole.name).subquery()

    # Comparing max version and role
    business_roles = db.session.query(BusinessRole).join(
        sub_query,
        and_(
            BusinessRole.version == sub_query.c.max_version,
            BusinessRole.updated_on == sub_query.c.latest_updated_on,
            BusinessRole.name == sub_query.c.name
        ))
```

so based on the example above I get these values

```
1. Business_Role_1, updated_on: 2023-05-02, version: 2
2. Business_Role_2, updated_on: 2023-04-30, version: 3
```

Now I want to sort these values based on the approver field of the Approval table, so I added this line to the query I have written.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload
business_roles = business_roles.options(joinedload(BRModel.BusinessRole.approval))
```

when I run this query
I get the results, but it is wrong, I do get the below warning.

```
SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "anon_2", "businessrole" and FROM element "approval".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.
items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
```

how do I resolve this?